# Are there any built-in functions to search sorted list?

Tags: vimscript, search, performance, list

Are there any built-in functions to search sorted list? Such as binary_search, lower_bound, upper_bound, etc.

Comment: I don't think so. I have used vimgrep to find something like that but came up empty.

Comment: Why do you need this? Vim has functions to search lists—do you need performance for a large data set? Push the code to a different level (ie out of vimscript), unless vim can expose the binary search mechanism it uses for tagsfiles.

Comment: Don't really need it, just curious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing built in. But you might check [lh-vim-lib](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-vim-lib).

It has the following functions working on sorted lists:

- `lh#list#equal_range()`
- `lh#list#lower_bound()`
- `lh#list#upper_bound()`

Comment: I do indeed provide these functions, but they are quite likely to be less efficient than a naive call to `filter()`. You'll have to measure both to see what's better suited to the data you're manipulating in your plugins.